# Cannot convert undefined or null to object - DynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Been testing some Lambda functions and finally managed to get the data to push to DyanmoDB, or at least in the logs it shows the billed duration and this only occurs after I've pushed data to the table, doesn't happen before I test the function.

Basically, I'm just testing a small function to push a UserID and Name to a DynamoDB table. I populate the params as seen below.

`var UserID = toAdd['UserID']; var Name = toAdd['Name'];`

`var params = { Item: { 'UserID':UserID, 'Name':Name }, TableName: 'bookings2D' };`

When I console log my params I'm seeing this:

[image: params]

`dynamo.putItem(params, dynamoResultCallback);`

And as you can see below, the request is at the very least being triggered.

[image: request]

However, when I navigate to my DB Table, and perform a table scan I receive this error:

[image: dynamo error]

This only occurs AFTER I run the Lambda function, if I delete and recreate the table this no longer appears. Seems like it's just something small format wise I may not be grasping.

Any help is much appreciated, any questions feel free to ask :)

Thanks

Comment: i have the same problem, but it still persists even after table was deleted and recreated (on the client side). turns out all i need is to do is to click the reload button of browser (not the refresh button in your screenshot, it doesn't help).

Answer (score 6):

Hard refresh your browser page using `CTRL + F5` or `CTRL + Shift + R`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue while creating table for phone (table name).

As a solution, I recreated the table with a different name (phone_detail).

AND IT WORKED!

[image]

You can also try to create table after a while.

[image]